# How to access attributes of a class from within it in C#

Tags: c#

I have these attributes for this class, and I am wondering how to access them from within the class. `ServedClassName` is a custom attribute, and that is the one I am actually trying to access.

```
[Guid("24889af6-e174-460b-ab52-7fb5a925926e")]
[ServedClassName("ASCOM ProxyClient Telescope")]
[ProgId("ASCOM.DeviceProxyClient.Telescope")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Telescope : ReferenceCountedObjectBase, ITelescopeV3
```

To access the ProgID, I use this: `Marshal.GenerateProgIdForType(this.GetType());`

Comment: Reflection not an option??

Comment: `TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w3a7b50%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  

`Type.GetCustomAttributes`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getcustomattributes.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
object [] attrs = GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ServedClassNameAttribute), true);
```

will give you a list of the custom attributes of type ServedClassNameAttribute on your class. You can then walk through the attribute instances like this:

```
foreach (ServedClassNameAttribute attr in attrs)
{
    // Do something with attr
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I use `(typeof(...),false)`? Visual studio is saying that it doesn't have an overload for just type. Or should I put true there?

Comment: My bad, I'll fix the answer. You want to use inherit=true if you are deriving from a class that also may have your attribute set on its type. If you only care about whether the current class has the attribute set and not its base class, use inherit=false.

Comment: If you just use `GetCustomAttributes(bool)` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx), you return all attributes for the current `Type` instance.